# angularfire $add not working

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm trying to do a simple CRUD with ionic (v1) and angularfire. I can read and delete records but I need to edit and create. The actual problem is angularfire function $add`, this function doesn't do anything and doesn't return any error in the console. I have this code:

```
    $scope.users = $firebaseArray(root.ref('/users/'));
    $scope.user = {};
    //Create
    $scope.title = "New user"
    $scope.button = "Create";
    $scope.icon = "ion-person-add";
    $scope.submit = function () {
        var data = {
            name: $scope.user.name,
            username: $scope.user.username,
            email: $scope.user.email,
            street: $scope.user.street,
            suite: $scope.user.suite,
            city: $scope.user.city,
            lat: $scope.user.lat,
            lng: $scope.user.lng,
            phone: $scope.user.phone,
            website: $scope.user.website,
        }
        console.log(data);
        $scope.users.$add(data).then(function (ref) {
            console.log('contact added with Id: ' + id);;
        })
```

Apparently the code is fine, but doesn't return `console.log` so maybe had some errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error fixed.

```
$scope.users = $firebaseArray(root.ref('/users/'));
            $scope.user = {};
            //Create
            $scope.title = "New user"
            $scope.button = "Create";
            $scope.icon = "ion-person-add";
            $scope.submit = function () {
                var data = {
                    name: $scope.user.name,
                    phone: $scope.user.phone,
                    email: $scope.user.email,
                    username: $scope.user.username,
                    city: $scope.user.city,
                    lat: $scope.user.lat,
                    lng: $scope.user.lng,
                    street: $scope.user.street,
                    suite: $scope.user.suite,
                    website: $scope.user.website,
                    zipcode: $scope.user.zipcode,
                }
                $scope.users.$add(data).then(function (response) {
                    if (response) {
                        $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: '<div><i class="ion-checkmark-circled"></i></div>',
                            subTitle: '<h4>The user <b>' + data.name + '</b> is added.</h4>',
                        });
                    }
                $scope.user=null;
```

With that all works properly and modal shows when we add user.

Answer (score 0):

Well to find out if there is any error Javascript `then` takes to call back one for success and the other for failure something like the code below

```
$scope.user.$add(data).then(function (success){
return console.log(success);
}, function(error){
return console.log(error);
})
```

Now that's for `then` that way you can log returned errors

Comment: The error is "Error: Key id was undefined. Cannot pass undefined in JSON. Use null instead."